# Is it possible to retrieve access token from Controller of the same server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have implemented the Sprint oauth2 security. I am getting access token when I use curl.

My doubt is, Is it possible to generate access token at Controller method ?
i.e. When I call login, I will pass user name and password, inside Controller login method, I would like to get the access token by using RestTemplate. Means I shall call the oauth url for the same server with needed parameters and I would like to get the access token for accessing the rest of resources as response of my login call.

For example,

- I will call http://localhost:8080/user/login
- Inside Controller method for /user/login, I will get my access token by using oauth url and parameters
- I will return access token as the response of my login call
- I will use that access token for rest of the secured apis.

When I tried this, it is showing unauthorized (401) error for /oauth/token url.

So Is it possible to do like this way, anybody has already tried this ?

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Hi,
Please find my codes below. I am using port 8081

Controller

```
 @PostMapping("/user/login")
public User login(@RequestBody User user) {

    ResponseEntity<String> response =null;

    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    String credentials = "client:secret";
    String credentialsEnc = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(credentials.getBytes()));

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    Map<String, String> uriVars = new HashMap<String, String>();
    uriVars.put("username", "user1");
    uriVars.put("password", "password");
    uriVars.put("grant_type", "password");
    uriVars.put("scope", "read");

    String accessTokenUrl = "http://localhost:8081/oauth/token";
        response = template.exchange(accessTokenUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class, uriVars);
    
    System.out.println("Access Token response-" +response);

    System.out.println("Authorization code-->" +response);

    return user;
}


@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer 
serverSecurityConfigurer) {
    serverSecurityConfigurer.resourceId("api");
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
            
}
}


@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Value("${jwt.clientId:client}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${jwt.client-secret:secret}")
private String clientSecret;

@Value("${jwt.signing-key:123}")
private String jwtSigningKey;

@Value("${jwt.accessTokenValidititySeconds:43200}") // 12 hours
private int accessTokenValiditySeconds;

@Value("${jwt.authorizedGrantTypes:password,authorization_code,refresh_token}")
private String[] authorizedGrantTypes;

@Value("${jwt.refreshTokenValiditySeconds:2592000}") // 30 days
private int refreshTokenValiditySeconds;

public AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                 UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient(clientId)
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValiditySeconds)
            .authorizedGrantTypes(authorizedGrantTypes)
            .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .resourceIds("api");
}


@Override
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Bean
JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    return converter;
}
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.userDetailsService =userDetailsService;
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    return provider;
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/**").permitAll().
            antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN").
            anyRequest().authenticated();

}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception{
    builder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select usrnam,usrpwd, case when usrsta='A' then true else false end from usrmst where usrnam=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select usrnam,usrtyp from usrmst where usrnam=?");
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

}

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can hit the token endpoints to get the access token. what attributes are you passing to the token endpoint? Are those endpoints are excluded in spring security config file?

Comment: You need to share the call details and spring security configurations for more information.

Comment: Hi harry, I have shared the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Used POST method by passing parameters in url without uri variables, it got worked.

Thanks..

Comment: Can you share the code here? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `token` using `OAuth2RestTemplate` on the same server

```
private OAuth2AccessToken getToken(LoginResource loginResource) {
    String access_token_url = "http://localhost:8081/api/oauth/token";
    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    resourceDetails.setGrantType("password");
    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(access_token_url);
    
        //-- set the clients info
    resourceDetails.setClientId("client_id");
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret("client_secret");
        
        // set scopes
    List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
    scopes.add("read"); 
    scopes.add("write");
    scopes.add("trust");
    resourceDetails.setScope(scopes);
        
    //-- set Resource Owner info
    resourceDetails.setUsername(loginResource.getUserName());
    resourceDetails.setPassword(loginResource.getPassword());
    OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);
    return oAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(); 
}
```